# How to approach this problem?

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling

I have 3 large datasets with 21 non-ordinal categorical variables and 1 variable date, representing data from month intervals in two years. The target variable is a categorical variable with multiple categories. I've tried time series approach without success, now I'm trying some clusterization but without success too.

I've processed the data removing missing values and useless columns, also I transformed the variables into dummy variables to perform cluster analysis, but once I do this, the RAM memory crashes.

Comment: Please update the title of your question, this doesn't provide any context and might keep people from providing you with useful answers